# Alignment in `longtable'

Tags: longtable, alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \pmb{Operation} & \pmb{Codes}   & \pmb{Output}\\\hline
    \endhead
    \multirow{3}{*}{Transpose}  &{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont A=Matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,1,5]])}  & \multirow{3}{*}{$\left(
    \begin{matrix}
        1 &2 &3\\
        3 &2 &1\\
        1 &1 &5
    \end{matrix}
    \right)$}\\

    & {\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont B=A.transpose()} &\\
    & {\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont show(B)} &\\\hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Determinant}    &{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont A=Matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,1,5]])}  & \multirow{2}{*}{-16}\\
    & {\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont A.det()} &   \\\hline 
    
    \multirow{3}{*}{Adjoint}    &{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont A=Matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,1,5]])}  & \multirow{3}{*}{$\left(
        \begin{matrix}
            1 &2 &3\\
            3 &2 &1\\
            1 &1 &5
        \end{matrix}
        \right)$}\\
    & {\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont B=A.adjugate()}  &\\
    &{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont show(B)}  &\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

It is appearing through my coding that

1. in the 3rd column (Output column), then parenthesis touched the top and bottom horizontal lines
2. also in the mid column, the lines are not left aligned.
   How can I solve these problems?

Comment: you have `\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}` so three centred columns use `l` if you want left. same as `tabular` or `array`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but with this, `Codes` will also be left aligned which I was not seeking

Comment: as with tabular `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Codes}}` will give a centred heading. don't use `\pmb` !!!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's really nice!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't require all those `\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
%%%\usepackage{multicol} % not needed
\usepackage{longtable}

% new:
\usepackage{array,courier}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| l | >{\ttfamily}l | c |}
    
\hline
\textbf{Operation} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Codes}}  & \textbf{Output}\\
\hline
\endhead
    
% body of table:
    \multirow{3}{*}{Transpose}  & 
    A=Matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,1,5]])  & 
    \multirow{3}{*}{\small $
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 &2 &3\\
            3 &2 &1\\
            1 &1 &5
        \end{pmatrix}
        $} \\

    & B=A.transpose() & \\
    & show(B) & \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Determinant}    &
    A=Matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,1,5]])  & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{$-16$}\\
    & A.det() & \\
    \hline  
    \multirow{3}{*}{Adjoint}    &
    A=Matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,1,5]])  & 
    \multirow{3}{*}{\small $
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 &2 &3\\
            3 &2 &1\\
            1 &1 &5
        \end{pmatrix}
        $} \\
    & B=A.adjugate()  & \\
    & show(B)  & \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up query: The two main macros provided by LaTeX for drawing horizontal lines in table-like structures -- `\hline` and `\cline` -- are not particularly sophisticated. In particular, the spacing between lines drawn by `\hline` and `\cline` and the material above/below the lines is frequently woefully inadequate. You've encountered this yourself, haven't you?

Now, one could try a "bandaid approach" to fixing this issue, by inserting some vertical whitespace padding, by hand, above or below various lines. I would like to recommend that you consider doing something very different: Load the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package and learn to use its user-level macros: `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\addlinespace`. Whitespace can be every bit as effective at forming a visual separator as a black line can. A happy side-effect of using the macros of the `booktabs` package is that it's hardly ever necessary to contemplate engaging in the kind of visual formatting you are mentioning in your follow-up comments.

Oh, getting rid of all vertical rules is also something that you should become very familiar with. Trust me, those vertical lines won't be missed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
%%%\usepackage{multicol} % not needed
\usepackage{longtable}

% new:
\usepackage{array,courier,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{} l >{\ttfamily}l c @{}}
    
    \toprule
    \textbf{Operation} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Codes}} & 
    \textbf{Output}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead

    \bottomrule 
    \endlastfoot
    
% body of table:
    \multirow{3}{*}{Transpose} & 
    A=Matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,1,5]]) & 
    \multirow{3}{*}{$
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 &2 &3\\
        3 &2 &1\\
        1 &1 &5
    \end{pmatrix}$} \\
   
  & B=A.transpose() &\\
  & show(B) & \\
    \addlinespace
    
    \multirow{2}{*}{Determinant} &
    A=Matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,1,5]]) & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{$-16$}\\
  & A.det() & \\
    \addlinespace 
    
    \multirow{3}{*}{Adjoint} &
    A=Matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,1,5]]) & 
    \multirow{3}{*}{$
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 &2 &3\\
        3 &2 &1\\
        1 &1 &5
    \end{pmatrix}$}\\
  & B=A.adjugate() & \\
  & show(B) & \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how can I manually set arbitrary cell height for a particular cell in this table?

Comment: @ManjoyDas - Please be a bit more specific. Which cell do you have in mind, and how large might the "arbitrary cell height" be?

Comment: the (3,2) cell with +0.5 cm height

Comment: @ManjoyDas - Am I interpreting your request correctly as  you wanting to adjust the height of cell (2,2) but not the heights of the adjoining cells (2,1) and (2,3)? I honestly don't know how that might be accomplished.

Comment: to be precise I want to increase the height of the `Determinant` row by 0.5 cm

Comment: @ManjoyDas - Please see the addendum I posted.

Comment: that's nice.....